# Region and Language & IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, globalization

I have an asp.net web application in one of our live servers. And just noticed that the **Region and Language** settings in the server were wrong.

Corrected it.

But do I need to reset the IIS or recycle the application pool for the changes to take effect in my application?

Comment: Careful - on the server you were logged in as administrator and when you changed the region settings, you probably just changed them for that account. It's unlikely (and ill-advised) to run your IIS applications as administrator (your application is probably running under a service account instead) and that is the account you'll need to change the settings for. As for whether it needs a restart to pull in the settings, I would assume so but unless your app can't have downtime I suggest just restarting the application.